# Add Object to Dictionary value in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dictionary

I got next code:

```
private Dictionary<int?, byte[]> GetAllLocalScanFiles()
{
    using (DZine_IStylingEntities ctxLocal = new DZine_IStylingEntities())
    {
        _scanDictionaryLocal = ctxLocal.tblScan
                .Select(s => new { s.MEMBERID, s.scanFileAvatar })
                .AsParallel()
                .ToDictionary(s => s.MEMBERID, s => s.scanFileAvatar);
    }
    return _scanDictionaryLocal;
}
```

I want to change the Ditionary in `Dictionary<int?, ScanClass>`

ScanClass is an Object

```
public class ScanClass
{
    public byte[] ScanFileAvatar { get; set; }
    public byte[] Hair { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to give an object for the value of a Dictionary? 
PS I don't want to do this with a lookup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want something like:

```
private Dictionary<int?, ScanClass> GetAllLocalScanFiles()
{
    using (DZine_IStylingEntities ctxLocal = new DZine_IStylingEntities())
    {
        return ctxLocal.tblScan
                 .Select(s => new { s.MEMBERID, s.scanFileAvatar, s.hair })
                 .AsParallel()
                 .ToDictionary(s => s.MEMBERID, s => new ScanClass {
                                   hair = s.hair,
                                   scanFileAvatar = s.scanFileAvatar
                               });
    }
}
```

That's assuming you have a `hair` property in your original entity.

It's not clear that `AsParallel` is really going to help you here though. You might want to consider using `AsEnumerable()` instead, unless you have a *reason* to parallelize this.

Comment: Jon quick question hair & scanFileAvatar are 2 big data prop of 20MB+ and if I execute this query I get an out of memory exception how can I avoid or fix this ?

Comment: @daageu: Presumably don't try to fetch the whole contains of the database in one go... there isn't really enough information about what you're trying to do to give a better answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
_scanDictionaryLocal = ctxLocal.tblScan
    .ToDictionary(s => s.MEMBERID, s => new ScanClass() 
    { 
      ScanFileAvatar = s.scanFileAvatar,
      Hair = s.hair
    });
```

Comment: I would just skip the `Select` and `AsParallel` and do `ToDictionary` directly